# Android: Listening to contact changes like WhatsApp do

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, android-syncadapter

I'm building an App which relies heavily on the user's contacts.

I've created an `Account` and create `RawContacts` on behalf of this account when needed.
And I use `SyncAdapter` and things are great.

But I'm still missing some parts of this puzzle:

I'm trying to implement a behavior similar to WhatsApp.  Such that-

**When a change happens in the name or phone of any contact - it would be sent to the server for evaluation**.

Whether this contact was already in "my" `RawContacts`, whether he was just created now by the user.

I know there's the `ContentObserver` but tracking `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` seems like the wrong thing to do because it doesn't give the specific change, plus it gets raised to many times,  and from to many events that don't interest me.

I know that WhatsApp are using SyncAdapter but I think they might be doing something more.

Any idea would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Hagai...hello any update about how you tackled this ?? I have used CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP in my code to get the latest updated contacts but this stamp does not change if you update any field in a  contact which has only email id with it.

Comment: @Hagai... hello... it would be great if you could share your findings by answering your own question if you have succeeded in solving it.

Comment: Hi, years have passed... and as far as I remember - I didn't get an answer that was good enough for what I've needed.

Answer (score 1):

`ContentObserver` tracking `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` is indeed the way to go.

When you get `onChange()` you query the `raw_contacts` table with following condition:

```
String where = "(rawcontacts.dirty = true or rawcontacts.deleted = 1) and rawcontacts.account_type = <your_custom_type>"
```

The result will give you contacts added, updated or deleted.

If you are interested in knowing more details - the reason why you need to subscribe to `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` is that the contacts provider currently does not notify which contacts were modified in onChange(). This is because of the `applyBatch()` transactions where multiple contacts may change. May be in future there will be a way to subscribe to a subset - but currently there is none.

Comment: It would be great if you could post a full example of how to do the `query` in `onChange()`.